# Как сделать так, чтобы Retrofit мог возвращать в одном запросе нужную модель и модель ошибки

Tags: java, android, retrofit

При удачном ответе от VK API приходит следующее:

```
{
    "response": {
        "count": 1000000001,
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 456240267,
                "album_id": 253599014,
                "owner_id": 24310980,
                "photo_75": "https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c845416\/v845416612\/42651\/q-voZCyMo7o.jpg",
                "photo_130": "https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c845416\/v845416612\/42652\/eA7NSK0l7tE.jpg",
                "photo_604": "https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c845416\/v845416612\/42653\/UU0BsIuFMy0.jpg",
                "photo_807": "https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c845416\/v845416612\/42654\/V5paYadJZtw.jpg",
                "width": 778,
                "height": 409,
                "text": "Играем тут => vk.com\/rucardsplay#al",
                "date": 1525193502
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

При возникновении ошибки приходит следующее(Совсем другая модель):

```
{
    "error": {
        "error_code": 5,
        "error_msg": "User authorization failed: invalid access_token (4).",
        "request_params": [
            {
                "key": "oauth",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "key": "method",
                "value": "photos.search"
            },
            {
                "key": "v",
                "value": "5.74"
            },
            {
                "key": "count",
                "value": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как обрабатывать и то, и то правильно? В обоих случаях приходит код 200.

Сейчас Callback выглядит вот так:

```
private Callback<ResponseModel> getLoadImagesCallback() {
        return new Callback<ResponseModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseModel> call,
                                   @NonNull Response<ResponseModel> response) {
                ImageItem[] items = response.body().getResponse().getImageItems();
                adapter.addListToEnd(items);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseModel> call,
                                  @NonNull Throwable t) {

            }
        };
    }
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я заведомо не стал полностью описывать поля класса Item для большей наглядности.

Используя аннотации [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) можно сделать так:

```
public class ResponseModel {

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("response")
    public Response response;

    public class Response {

        @Nullable
        @SerializedName("count")
        public Integer count;

        @Nullable
        @SerializedName("items")
        public List<Item> items;

        public class Item {

           @Nullable
           @SerializedName("id")
           public Long id;

        }

    }

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("error")
    public Error error;

    public class Error {

        @Nullable
        @SerializedName("error_code")
        public Integer errorCode;

        @Nullable
        @SerializedName("error_msg")
        public String errorMessage;

        @Nullable
        @SerializedName("request_params")
        public List<RequestParameter> requestParams;

        public class RequestParameter {

           @Nullable
           @SerializedName("key")
           public String key;

           @Nullable
           @SerializedName("value")
           public String value;

        }

    }

}
```

А в вашем `callback` при проверкe ответа просто проверяйте `responseModel.response` или `responseModel.error` на `null`